# Purpose of using mavenized Bootstrap

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, maven, jsp, taglib

In [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages), we can easily use [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) classes like in HTML. But I've seen that in some projects, people use taglibs for this manner by adding a Maven dependency like:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.efsavage.twitter.bootstrap</groupId>
     <artifactId>bootstrap-maven</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then including a taglib in their JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://efsavage.com/twitter-bootstrap" prefix="bs" %>
```

And finally using its tags like:

```
<bs:button text="submit" />
```

My question is when and why this way would be better than normally linking a Twitter Bootstrap CSS file and using its classes in our JSP pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons for this. When you want to include a 3rd party CSS or JavaScript resource, you have two choices:

- Point directly at an external resource that serves it
- Download it and include it in your project

Pointing at external resources can be problematic: those can die at anytime or simply be temporarily down. With such an approach, you are dependent on something outside of your control, which is generally a bad idea.

This leave the approach of downloading it manually and including it in the project. Conceptually, this is like depending on a library and Maven is the tool that is supposed to handle that. Hence adding this as a Maven dependency makes sense: you are declaring that your project is dependent on an external resource.

From [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/efsavage/Bootstrap-Maven):

> This library gives you a way to drop Twitter Bootstrap into your project as a Maven dependency, which means you don't have to include these third party files in your own source control.

Comment: I agree that relying on external resources is a bad idea and generally your point about maven is true. I still think including it in our project resources and using simple html tags gives us more flexibility to be consonant with future bootstrap updates or changing the framework. In these cases we would need just changing class values or css files. In addition if we're already experienced using bootstrap, we may profit our experiences using it the same way.

Comment: @Ali_Seyedi Well, with a Maven dependency, an update is just a single change in the `<version>`  element. You don't even need to download anything manually ;).

Comment: Just two final things: 1. Is it possible to use maven but not taglib for this?! 2. Can we be sure that the dependency will be updated?

Comment: @Ali_Seyedi 1. You'll have to use a taglib but that's the standard way of doing it. 2. The dependency used will be the one mentioned in the POM. If you want to update, you'll change the version and it'll be automatically updated.

Comment: for 2nd question I meant if bootstrap updates, will dependency owner update its version that we can refer to that by changing the version? There is no guarantee, right?

Comment: @Ali_Seyedi That is correct, it is unfortunately not guaranteed.